# Having issue with looping through dynamic mysql data array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array, an example being..

```
Array
(
    [cats] => Resource id #54
    [listings] => Array
        (
            [home-and-garden] => Resource id #55
            [professional-services] => Resource id #56
            [community] => Resource id #57
            [education-and-instruction] => Resource id #58
            [automotive] => Resource id #59
            [legal-and-financial] => Resource id #60
        )

)
```

Now, the `cats` key is a MySQL data set, which I have no issues looping through with `mysql_fetch_array`; however once inside that loop I try and run another loop on a certain key of the listings array, such as `home-and-garden`, all the keys under the listings array are dynamic, so I have to pass in a variable with the key name, however it won't enter the loop.

Below is an example of my code..

```
protected function makePopularCategoryHTML($sql) {

    while (list($main_category,$slug,$image)=mysql_fetch_array($sql['cats'])) {

        // Make lowercase category slug
        $main_category_slug = URLSafe($main_category);

        while (list($category,$name,$tag1,$newurl)=mysql_fetch_array($sql['listings'][$main_category_slug])) {

            // It won't enter this loop                

        }

    }

}
```

**Edit:** Dump of an example `$sql['listings'][$main_category_slug]` is below:

```
resource(55) of type (mysql result)
```

Dump of `$sql['listings']` is below:

```
array(6) {
  ["professional-services"]=>
  resource(55) of type (mysql result)
  ["home-and-garden"]=>
  resource(56) of type (mysql result)
  ["community"]=>
  resource(57) of type (mysql result)
  ["food-and-dining"]=>
  resource(58) of type (mysql result)
  ["real-estate"]=>
  resource(59) of type (mysql result)
  ["business-to-business"]=>
  resource(60) of type (mysql result)
}
```

They all appear to be valid resources and I have checked that the key name is correct.

Comment: You're aware that `mysql_fetch_array()` without a second parameter will return _both_ numeric and associative keys, right? so `list()` won't get the values you expect.  Instead call as `mysql_fetch_array($sql['cats'], MYSQL_ASSOC)` or use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` for both those loops.

Comment: And What is in `$sql['listings'][$main_category_slug]`? Is it actually a mysql result resource?

Comment: check that you're not calling mysql_free_result() somewhere for your resources... also, could you possibly include a dump of the mysql_fetch_array($sql['listings'][$main_category_slug]) part?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes I'm aware that it returns both and I don't really need both, it's just a bad habit of mine to keep using it. However, I have never has issues using it like that in the past.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski As you can see in the example array output above `$sql['listings'][$main_category_slug]` is a MySQL resource. `$main_category_slug` is equal to one of those names.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter I have included some dumps above.

Comment: what if you manually try to debug it as: `while( ... mysql_fetch_array('professional-services'))` ... does that work?

Comment: @ZathrusWriter I thought of doing that, but seeing as the values aren't always the same I can't always rely on a particular value being there. I suppose I could retrieve them all for testing purposes though to make sure it's there.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter Ok, just checked and it still didn't enter the loop even if I set it like you suggested. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

The array it wouldn't go into was empty because I assumed since I wasn't getting any errors from the respective queries that the query was ok, but it wasn't - one of the search parameters was blank.

If you are getting problems like this, *always* output the respective query and run it manually to see if you have an empty result set.